# How to use PHP7's $mysqli->real_escape_string with an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, php-7

Before PHP7, I would combine `implode` and `array_map` to go through each of the values with `mysql_real_escape_string` to prepare them for a statement to avoid sql injection. e.g:

```
$values = implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $sqlArray));
```

`mysql_real_escape_string` has been replaced now by [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). How would the above code be done with the new methods just as easily using the mysqli class in an array_map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be better off using prepared statements, but to the question, pass an array of object and method.  This should work for anything that takes a callback:

```
$result = array_map(array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'), $sqlArray);
```

Assuming you have a `$mysqli` object that you're working with from the [mysqli class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: Ok so now : _What is `$mysqli`_

Comment: Thanks, yeah I already have a $mysqli object. Many thanks Abra

Comment: Yea, I get that, but others may not. If you want your answer to be usful to others less intuitive than us, it would be useful to make that obvious in your answer